# jquery change page automatic when function success

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using header on php when I want to change after function. Now I want to use on jQuery.

```
if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
                
    setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);
    return window.location = index.php;
}
```

This line does not work - I want to change page when `.hasClass('success')`

```
return window.location = index.php;
```

I tried without return again did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('form #response').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

I changed your `settimeout` to have a function, which calls the `fadeOut` on `#response`, and once that's finished it calls `window.location.href` and changes it to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` requires quotes around the page. Try this code instead:

```
window.location = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting window.location (which returns a Location object - it's a read-only property), try setting window.location.href.  Also, make sure you assign it a string.  Here's an example:

```
window.location.href = "index.php";
```

Comment: Actually, `window.location` is read/write. You're thinking of `document.location`. (and even then, that's only read only in IE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('form #response').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000);
    return window.location = 'index.php';
}//END IF
```

Also make sure it is wrapped in the `$(function() { });`